# How to create a drop down by fetchng the elements from other table(in rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Say I have created to two scaffold service and home..I want a list of  services in a drop down in home controller.As I'm new to rails ..please help me

Answer (score 0):

"drop down in home controller" is not a clear statement, but if you're saying you want to be able to select a service in a view, you can define a form and include a select_tag

```
select_tag "service_id", options_from_collection_for_select(Service.all, "id", "name")
```

This assumes a service has a column `name` which is the text you want to appear on the drop-down.